# Java Spark Dataset retrieve cell value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

My Dataset looks like below, i want to fetch the 1st row,1st column value (A1 in this case)

```
 +-------+---+--------------+----------+
 |account|ccy|count(account)|sum_amount|
 +-------+---+--------------+----------+
 |     A1|USD|             2|    500.24|
 |     A2|SGD|             1|    200.24|
 |     A2|USD|             1|    300.36|
 +-------+---+--------------+----------+
```

I can do this as below :

```
 Dataset finalDS = dataset.groupBy("account", "ccy").
    agg(count("account"), sum("amount").alias("sum_amount"))
    .orderBy("account", "ccy");

Object[] items = (Object[])(finalDS.filter(functions.col("sum_amount")
    .equalTo(300.36))
    .collect());

String accountNo =  (String)((GenericRowWithSchema)items[0]).get(0);
```

2 questions :

1. Any other/more efficient way to do this ? I am aware of `Dataframe/JavaRDD` queries
2. Without the explicit cast `Object[]`, there is a compile time failure, however I would have thought that this is an implicit cast. Why ? I suspect something to do with scala compilation.

Comment: Have you tried `finalDS.first().getString(0)` ?

Comment: first().getString(0) works, thank you !                                                                         
And if i want the 2nd row,4th col - 300.36 in this case,  (((Row [])dataset.head(3))[1].getDouble(3)  (Aware of the performance considerations of head(n) etc. )

Answer (score -1):

> Any other/more efficient way to do this ? I am aware of Dataframe/JavaRDD queries

You'd better use `Dataset.head` ([javadocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#head--)) function in order to eliminate passing all the data to driver process. This will limit you to loading only 1st row to driver RAM instead of the entire dataset. You also can consider using [take](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#take-int-) function to obtain first N rows.

> Without the explicit cast Object[], there is a compile time failure, however I would have thought that this is an implicit cast. Why ? I suspect something to do with scala compilation.

It depends on how your dataset is typed. In case of `Datarame` (which is `Dataset[Row]`, [proof](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/689de920056ae20fe203c2b6faf5b1462e8ea73c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/package.scala#L46)), you'll get an `Array[Row]` on call to `collect`. It's worth to mention the signature of [collect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c4bb486b29a8fd89ebf746c150aa7175aded15a7/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2788) functions:

```
  def collect(): Array[T] = withAction("collect", queryExecution)(collectFromPlan)
```

Comment: Where is Java here ? This reply does not match the question

Comment: `You'd better use Dataset.head (javadocs)`.
Java is in the above quote, following javadocs link. `Dataset.head` is more efficient way than collecting the whole data and iterating over it on Spark Driver side.
Scala snippet is just a copy of source code you can find when follow the link for `collect` function